# Why isn't glibc installed by default?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, glibc

According to wikipedia, glibc is a very widely used library in unix/linux, so since it's so popular, why isn't it installed to system by default?

Comment: glibc should be installed with almost all systems as ALOT of things use it, refer to cnicutars answer. You might be confusing it with glib2

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing **[glibc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/)** with **[glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/)**. glib2 is only installed if there are applications that need it.

Answer (score 1):

I see the `linux-kernel` tag on your question, so I am guessing you are asking why GNU `libc` is not part of the kernel. The simple answer is that `libc` in general is the [user-land](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) library providing generic/standard application interface over varying set of OS kernel [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).